# How to view the most up voted issues in GitHub?

Tags: github

I've got a project with many open issues and I'm trying to make sense of what should be done first.

Users often add a "thumb up" when an issue is relevant to them, however I haven't found out any way to see which issues received the most "thumb up".

Is there any built-in or even external tool to find out about this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not about programming

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clicking sort by & and a reaction (thumbs up in your case) it should show issues with the most thumbs up reactions.

[image]